# Swapping Data Views for SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to edit an SSRS report to point to some different data.

Currently the report is working fine, pointing to a view (myView1) containing the data it needs.

I have another view with more data in it (myView2). I have ensured that all the columns in myView2 are exactly the same as myView1, including data types, names, case sensitivity of column names etc.

I had hoped that I could just rename myView1 to myView0, then rename myView2 to myView1 and the report would simply take the data from the new view, but the report then tells me that it contains No Data.

If I revert the views to their original names the report works fine again.

I have tried redefining myView1 so it contains the same data as myView2 but I get the same error. When I revert the definitions the report works fine again.

Is there some trick I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: When you renamed the views, did you refresh the data-source?

Answer (score 0):

As Ross Bush mentioned in the comments:

> When you renamed the views, did you refresh the data-source?

refreshing the data-source solved the issue.